# Exact meaning of weights in SOLR ranking

Tags: solr

I have been trying different weights on SOLR dismax and edismax ranking and got to wonder what these weights mean? For example, you can specify qf parameter something like this:

```
qf:title^2.0 body^1.0 ...
```

What do these weights mean? Is it multiplication of each field's text score? Or is it addition?

Also how about pf parameter?

```
pf:title^2.0 body^0.5
```

Is it also multiplication or addition?

If someone could shed some light, that will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qf -> is for query fields which measures score for individual terms.
boost multiplies the weight to the individual match score for the field

e.g. `qf:title^2.0 body^1.0` document with match on the title field will have double the score then a document with a match on boby (given all the other factors are same)

pf -> is for phrase query which measures score for phrase terms

e.g. for query `internet banking` and Configuration `qf:title^2.0 body^1.0` and `pf:title^2.0 body^0.5`

should result in query :-

```
title:internet^2 title:banking^2  
body:internet^1 body:banking^1  
title:"internet banking"^2 body:"internet banking"^0.5
```